# Difference between: ./gradlew lint and Analyze -> Inspect Code

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I have different results from running ./gradlew lint and different ones when I click Analyze -> Inspect Code. Do you know why these differences and how to make it consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different tools/checks

The Analyse feature is an Android Studio/Intellij tool which includes much more checks. (But lint checks are also included)

So if you change the Analyse Settings you wont influence the results of the gradlew lint check. The lint check runs a predifined set of checks, which are listed [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks).

To get the same results you would have to deactivate any additional checks, which are not included in the set of predefined lint checks.

You can also configure which checks are done in the lint check. But you can't run the Intellij Analyse features with the lint tool.